# bash script to read info from a file

Tags: bash, shell

how can i make a bash script to tell the script this:

i will tell the bash like:

```
#!/bin/bash
include /usr/local/serverinfo.txt or.sh

rsync -avz $location root@$host:/$location2
```

all of this `$location`, `$host` , `$location2`, to be entered in `/usr/local/serverinfo.txt`

how can i tell the bash script to get this infos from the file,

if i put them in the same file will work just perfect, however i whant it to be outside of the file, any ideea?

let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`source`](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html), or equivalently `.`, which takes another file as an argument and executes it. This assumes that the file you are `source`ing contains valid bash syntax.

**script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
var=1

source inc.sh          # or . inc.sh
echo $var
```

**inc.sh**

```
var=2
```

output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how the data in `serverinfo.txt` is formatted.
If it is a simple list like

```
/this/is/the/first/location
/this/is/the/host
/this/is/the/second/location
```

then you can do

```
location=$(sed -n '1p' /path/to/serverinfo.txt)
host=$(sed -n '2p' /path/to/serverinfo.txt)
location2=$(sed -n '3p' /path/to/serverinfo.txt)
```

Comment: my ideea is to name like: info=1 ,info2=2, but if your ideea works, i can also set them like 1,2,3,4 it will not be a problem for me.